# Como posso resolver uma "referencia indefinida"?

Tags: c

Estou começando agora nesta vida de programador e estou tentando realizar um programa para aula de física mas na hora de compilar o arquivo está me voltando esta mensagem... alcance.c:(.text+0x68): referência indefinida para `cos'
alcance.c:(.text+0x93): referência indefinida para`sin'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

estou usando o emacs... gcc -lm -o alcance alcance.c,
Devo enviar outras informações??

---

Esta é a parte que se refere ao consseno e ao seno
 rx=0.0;
  ry=0.0;
  vx=v0*cos(theta*3141592/180.0);
  vy=v0*sin(theta*3.141592/180.0);
Devo fazer o double cos, e double sin?

---

```js
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
 main () 
{
  double ry;
  double rx;
  double vx;
  double vy;
  double ax;
  double ay;
  double dt;
  double t;
  double g;
  double v0;
  double theta;
  double b; // [1/ms]coeficiente de arrasto
  double  dtheta; // angulo de lancamento

  g=-10;
  dt=0.1;// 
  v0=100;// velocidade inicial
  dtheta=1;// angulo de lançamente
  b=1;// coeficiente de arrato
  for (theta=0;theta<=90;theta=theta=dtheta){
    rx=0.0;
  ry=0.0;
  vx=v0*cos(theta*3141592/180.0);
  vy=v0*sin(theta*3.141592/180.0);

  
 for(t=0;t<=500;t=t+dt){

   if(ry<0.0)break;
   ax=0.0-b*vx;
   ay=-g-b*vy;
   rx=rx+vx*dt;
   ry=ry+vy*dt;
   vx=vx=ax*dt;
   vy=vy+ay*dt;
 }
#include <math.h>
 printf("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n",theta,t,rx,ry,vx,vy);
  }  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Você tentou compilar colocando `-lm` no final conforme sugerido pelo @pmg ?

Answer (score 4):

Mete as bibliotecas no fim do comando

```
gcc -o alcance alcance.c -lm
```

De acordo com o [manual do gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.1.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)

> [...] It makes a difference where in the command you write this option [...]

Comment: Como vou por a biblioteca no fim? ela já esta no topo #include <studio.h>
#include <math.h>

Comment: Estou escrevendo um programa em `C++` para um microcontrolador usando o `avr-gcc` de compilador. Estou tendo o seguinte erro: `neuronio.cpp:(.text._ZN8neuronioC2Eii+0x42): referência indefinida para operator new[](unsigned int)`. Eu posso mesmo usar um new? Algumas pessoas me falaram que é impossível criar um objeto em um µC, mas estou convencido de que posso fazê-lo. Poderias me ajudar?

Comment: no fim **do comando**, na linha de comandos. Em vez de `gcc -lm ...` usa `gcc ... -lm`

Comment: fiz este lance da biblioteca, "Arquivo ou diretorio não encontrado"

Comment: @Avelino Se tiver dúvidas, faça uma nova pergunta no site. O [pt.so] não funciona como um fórum tradicional. Abraço!